# how to pin a note and sort it in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, sorting

I was creating a notes app in react which has a pin functionality such that when I click on the pin icon on a particular note that particular note is displayed first. the user should only be able to pin 2 notes (and I've added that condition) the problem is The pin functionality is working perfectly fine but when I again click on a pinned note I want to un-pin it and again arrange it back in its place, how can i achieve this?

React code =

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "../styles/Notes.css";
import { useToast, Wrap, WrapItem, Button } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { BsFillPinFill } from "react-icons/bs"
import { BsTrashFill } from "react-icons/bs"
import { BsPinAngle } from "react-icons/bs";


function NotesComponent() {

  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [tagline, setTagline] = useState("");
  const [body, setBody] = useState("");
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);


  const toast = useToast()


  // submit handler
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!title || !tagline || !body) {
      toast({
        title: 'Please complete the input',
        status: 'error',
        duration: 9000,
        isClosable: true,
      });
      return;
    }


    // generating randome number to use as id 
    function generateUniqueNumber() {
      let uniqueNumber = "";
      while (uniqueNumber.length < 4) {
        let digit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        if (!uniqueNumber.includes(digit)) {
          uniqueNumber += digit;
        }
      }
      return uniqueNumber;
    }

    let number = generateUniqueNumber();


    setNotes([...notes, { title, tagline, body, pinned: false, id: number }]);
    setTitle("");
    setTagline("");
    setBody("");
  };


  // executing on click on the pen icon
  const togglePin = (index) => {
    setNotes(
      notes.map((note, i) => {
        if (i === index) {
          let newNote = { ...note };
          newNote.pinned = !note.pinned;
          return newNote;
        }
        return note;
      })
    );
  };



  // sorting it
  const sortedNotes = notes.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.pinned === b.pinned) {
        return 0;
      }
      return a.pinned ? -1 : 1;
    })
    .map((note, i) => {
      let newNote = { ...note };
      if (note.pinned) {
        const pinnedCount = notes.filter((n) => n.pinned).length;
        if (pinnedCount > 2) {
          newNote.pinned = false;
        }
      }
      return newNote;
    });


  const pages = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  const pageChnageHandler = (e) => {
    setPage(e.target.innerText);
  };



  const deleteHandler = (id) => {

    let index = id

    const newArrayAfterDeleting = notes.filter((item) => item.id !== index)

    setNotes(newArrayAfterDeleting)


  }



  return (
    <div className="notes-app-container">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="notes-form">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Title"
          value={title}
          onChange={(event) => setTitle(event.target.value)}
          className="notes-input"
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Tagline"
          value={tagline}
          onChange={(event) => setTagline(event.target.value)}
          className="notes-input"
        />
        <textarea
          placeholder="Body"
          value={body}
          onChange={(event) => setBody(event.target.value)}
          className="notes-textarea"

        />
        <button type="submit" className="notes-button">
          Add Note
        </button>
      </form>
      <div className="enteredNotesMainParent">

        {sortedNotes.slice(page * 6 - 6, page * 6).map((note, i) => (
          <div key={i} className="enteredNoteIndivitual">
            <div>{note.title}</div>
            <div>{note.tagline}</div>
            <div>{note.body}</div>
            <br />
            <div className="noteCtaHold">

              <div>
                <BsFillPinFill className="noteIcon" onClick={() => togglePin(i)} />
              </div>

              <div>
                <BsTrashFill className="noteIcon" onClick={() => deleteHandler(note.id)} />
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        ))}

      </div>

      {notes.length === 0 ? <p> Add some notes✅ </p> : ""}

      {notes.length >= 4 && <div className="pagesHold">
        {pages.map((item) => {
          return <p onClick={pageChnageHandler} className="indivitualPage"> {item} </p>
        })}
      </div>}




    </div>
  );
}

export default NotesComponent;
```

can somebody please help me achieve this that if a note is pinned and if I click on that  pinned note it should get un-pinned and re arrange back

Comment: Have you considered not sorting the pinned items to the top at all, and instead just filtering them out of the list when you render the unpinned items?

Comment: No but that is the task That If the user pins a particular note I should be displaying it on top hence I have to use the sort function. Can you probably help me

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily have to use `sort()` to get the pinned notes on top.

Just render the list twice: once for the pinned notes, filtering out the unpinned ones, and again for the rest of the list, filtering the pinned ones.

This way you don't have to concern yourself with where a given note is within the original list, because the original list doesn't change.

```js
// creates a list of sample notes; not relevant to the funcionality.
const notes = Array.from({length: 6}, (_, i) => ({
  title: `Note ${i + 1}`,
  id: i
}))

function Notes ({notes}) {
  // keep a list of the pinned note ids
  const [pinned, setPinned] = React.useState([]);
  
  // filter to get separate lists of pinned and unpinned notes
  const pinnedNotes = notes.filter(({ id }) => pinned.includes(id));
  const unpinnedNotes = notes.filter(({ id }) => !pinned.includes(id));
  
  // to pin a note: add its id to the pinned list
  const pin = id => setPinned([...pinned, id]);
  
  // to unpin a note: remove its id from the pinned list
  const unpin = id => {
    pinned.splice(pinned.indexOf(id), 1);
    setPinned([...pinned]);
  }
  
  // render both lists
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <ul className="pinned">
        { pinnedNotes.map(note => (
          <li key={note.id} onClick={() => unpin(note.id)}>{note.title}</li>
        ))}
       </ul>
       <ul className="unpinned">
        { unpinnedNotes.map(note => (
          <li key={note.id} onClick={() => pin(note.id)}>{note.title}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

const root = ReactDOM.render(<Notes notes={notes} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
/* all cosmetic. not necessary for it to work. */
.container {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.pinned {
  background: skyblue;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 0.5em;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}

.pinned:empty::after {
  content: "No pinned items. Click a note below to pin it.";
  padding: 1rem;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.unpinned:empty::after {
  content: "No unpinned notes.";
  padding: 1rem;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.pinned li {
  background: aliceblue;
}

.unpinned {
  background: aliceblue;
}

li {
  margin: 0.5em 0;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid steelblue;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```